# Does $\sin(\frac{z}{z-1})$ have a removable singularity at $z=1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Intuitively, I know that the singularity at $z=1$ of $f(z)=\sin(\frac{z}{z-1})$ can’t be removed because $\lim_{z \rightarrow 1} f(z)$ isn‘t even defined. But in complex analysis we defined $a$ to be a removable singularity of any holomorphic function g:

$g: \Omega \setminus \{a\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $ \ \ \Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ open

if $\lim_{z\rightarrow a} (z-a)g(z) = 0$.

And this is true for my function f because sin is bounded as z gets to 1 and $(z-a)$ goes to 0, isn‘t it?

Comment: Your flaw is thinking that $\sin z$ is bounded. For complex numbers $z$, $\sin z$ is *unbounded*.

Comment: Even as z gets to 1 (and therefore Im(z) goes to 0)?

Comment: Correct. If $z\to1$ in such a way that $z/(1-z)$ is purely imaginary, then $\sin(z/(1-z))$ grows exponentially.

Comment: Yes, you‘re completely right. Thank you so much!